# Separate categories for post types

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

Is there any way to create custom post type with separate categories in `wordpress`?

**Example**:

Post type "*News*" should have categories "*World*" and "*Local*".
Post type "*Products*" should have `categories`: "*Software*" and "*hardware*"
and I do not want to have option to set "*Software*" category to "*News*" post type.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Trust your editors do you really need that level of granularity?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create custom post type by following example code:

```
function ts_post_type_test() {
    register_post_type( 'Test',
                array( 
                'label' => __('Test'), 
                'public' => true, 
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'texonomies' => array('category'),
                'supports' => array( 'title','editor','thumbnail'),
                ) 
    );
}
```

the wordpress site link :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

For the Create separate  category for particular post use following link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Example code:

```
register_taxonomy('name of taxonomy', 'post name',array("hierarchical" => true,"label" => "Label Category","singular_label" => "label of taxonomy",'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count','query_var' => true,'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'slug name of new registered taxonomy', 'with_front' => false ),'public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_tagcloud' => true,'_builtin' => false,'show_in_nav_menus' => false));
```

Comment: not sure about `singular_label`, seems nothing like that is in the linked docs